# Generation of a symmetric encryption key in TPM

Tags: trusted-platform-module

I know that keys in a TPM key hierarchy are encrypted with their parent keys. And I read that those parent keys (for instance an asymmetric SRK) need to have some symmetric secret for said encryption.

1. Is it mandatory to encrypt child keys with a symmetric key or can I use the asymmetric keys as well?
2. And if I can only use the symmetric ones, how are they generated? In the official specification, it is stated, that a symmetric key is "derived from a seed value in the sensitive area of the Storage Key". But what does that mean? Where exactly is that seed value stored? Is it the private key of the parent? Or is it another attribute entirely?